# How to consume less power in ubuntu?

Tags: power-management

I noticed when I installed Ubuntu that it consumed more power, so I want to know how to reduce power consumption.I want the steps please.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple ways are available to save power in Ubuntu, but because of instability , most of them are not enabled by default. Few things you can do to extend  battery life of your laptop are mentioned below.

- **Enter into low power mode**

  In order to enter low power mode, run this:

  `sudo pm-powersave true`
- **Adjust Laptop Backlight**

  On a typical laptop dropping from full brightness to 2/3 brightness will save about 1 Watt.
- **Disable Unused Bluetooth Devices**.
- **Enable i915 LVDS Downclocking**

  It  will down-clock the LVDS refresh rate. For systems that do not support LVDS down-clocking the screen can flicker.
  edit /etc/default/grub to enable it.

  change:

  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

  to:

  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.lvds_downclock=1"`
- **Enable Aggressive Link Power Management**

  It  is a mechanism where a SATA AHCI controller can put the SATA link that     connects to the disk into a very low power mode during periods of zero I/O activity and into an active power state when work needs to be done.

  Enable ALPM:

  `echo SATA_ALPM_ENABLE=true | sudo tee /etc/pm/config.d/sata_alpm`
- **Use powertop**

  Powertop is a power consumption and power management diagnosis tool. Use it to send the following app in "Good" power saving state.

  - Webcam
  - Audio
  - DRAM
  - Ethernet
  - Wifi
  - Bluetooth
  - SATA link
  - MMC/SD
- **Reduce Wakeup Events**

  Wakeup events in applications cause an idle processor to come out of a sleep state and this consumes power.
  You can save few  wakeups in a second. For example, just disabling the gnome-terminal cursor flash will save wakeup events.

You can also use `Laptop Mode Tools`.It  is the primary way to enable the Laptop Mode feature of the Linux kernel, which lets your hard drive spin down. In addition, it allows you to tweak a number of other power-related settings using a simple configuration file.

[image]

***Install Laptop Mode Tools***

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/unstable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

Open it using `gksu lmt-config-gui`.

**[Source:wiki.ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks)**

Comment: Can you explain what is  LVDS refresh rate?!

Comment: Don't have much idea. But what I know is it(low-voltage differential signalling) is a high-speed digital interface that is used for several applications that require high noise immunity and low power consumption for high data rates

Comment: You said that it consume low power,So why should i down it?

Comment: I said downclocling, decreasing clock speed.